# how can I write that someone that someone is opening a door quickly with an obvious over-eagerness but not violently nor in a brutal way?

Tags: word-request

I'm struggling to find a word that reflects over-eagerness and a quick gesture that does not imply violence nor brutality of a door opening.

for some context: the main character wakes up on a bed, which isn't the one they remember sleeping on in clothes that aren't theirs, then, suddenly, the door of the room gets unlocked and here is where the door part is

Comment: Does such a word exist in your language? If yes, have you tried translating it to English? If no, why do you think the word exists in English?

Comment: "Someone _flung_ open the door"? (If the door suddenly opens, how does the person in the room _know_ whether the one coming in has violent intentions or not?)

Comment: Do you want a verb? There's no shortage of adverbs and adjectives, but possibly not a verb with the precise meaning (that's why we have adverbs).

Comment: @kate That cou;d be an answer

Answer (score 0):

If the story is written from the point of view of the person in the room, they don't know whether the person coming in has violent intentions or not; only that the door opens suddenly. You could say "Someone flung open the door" (or "The door was flung open").

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few adverbial candidates: eagerly, brusquely, sharply, swiftly, urgently, pressingly, smoothly, quickly, insistently, assertively, immediately, breezily, harshly, inhesitantly, sweepingly, confidently, abruptly, discordantly, indecorously,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which of the words might be apropos could depend on further detail in the question, such as what awakens the person, or why the opening of the door is the first reported event subsequent to the ascertainment of the unfamiliar circumstances.